# How do I implement a Facebook login button?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, oauth

I have tried to use the facebook login button to no avail, I am now using JavaScript to try and get the access token and store it in a variable, to no avail! I am tempted to quit my project, I have been trying this nonstop for 6 hours now. Please help me!

Comment: Please add some code to show what you've done so far. At the moment your question is far too broad to answer. Please look at [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login

Answer (score 0):

TO apply facebook login you just have to visit 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/howto/jquery/v2.8

I hope it will help you , you can learn to integrate it using angular js, require js and much more. I hope it will help you and it's simple.